# ImportError only when I package it with py2exe, other way it works

Tags: python, windows, import, py2exe, importerror

I am having problems I've never had with imports. In fact I have similar projects working correctly and I don't know what is going wrong with it particularly.

I have the following folders structure.

[image]

This is the error I get when I run the .exe once packaged with py2exe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named IODwsfe.core.IAdapter
```

And this is the way I do the import in `main.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import dbf

from IODwsfe.core.IAdapter import IAdapter
...
```

The `setup.py` I am using is configured the same way many other projects I developed!. in fact it is working because it creates a `.exe`. I cannot understand what is happening because I have sub-packages in each one of my projects; it is the first time something like this happens to me!

The project is working completely if I run it from console! It is so frustrating not being able to get it working completely. I have tried with PyInstaller and cx_freeze and I still get the same ImportError.

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't work at night or without sleeping well.

I just removed the `sys.path.append("src")` line from `setup.py` by mistake which allows py2exe to locate my own packages in `src` folder.